# Curl download small part of archive

Tags: curl, msys

I try to download some archive using curl under MSYS2. The size of original archive is about 960 Kb, but after executing curl command, size of downloaded archive is only 88 Kb. The way, I download it is:

```
curl -OL https://github.com/google/protobuf/releases/tag/v3.6.1/protoc-3.6.1-win32.zip
```

Answer (score 1):

The download link, which is formed in my code above this command, was wrong. The right one was:

```
curl -OL https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/releases/download/v3.6.1/protoc-3.6.1-win32.zip
```